# JAVA JAX-WS Deployment (JAVA Eclipse EE IDE)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently working on this tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/articles/jax-ws-hello-world and I'm new to all of this and am looking for some assistance. I get to step 5) where i run the WSPublisher. So I have the project set up in a Dynamic Web Project and when i run the WSPublisher file i use (1) Run on server. Im currently using Apache Tomcat/7.0.53. And i end up getting an HTTP Status 404 - error. Any tips on this 5 minute tutorial would be great as i could easily understand it further.

```
package juma.mohammad;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface Greeting {
     @WebMethod String sayHello(String name);
}
```

..

```
package juma.mohammad;

import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "juma.mohammad.Greeting")
public class GreetingImpl implements Greeting {

    @Override
    public String sayHello(String name) {
        return "Hello, Welcom to jax-ws " + name;
    }

}
```

..

```
package juma;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

import juma.mohammad.GreetingImpl;

public class WSPublisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting",new GreetingImpl());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Eclipse simply run main class i.e. WSPublisher . Now your webservice will be hosted. No need to do anything. Now download soap ui and use it as client by importing your wsdl i.e. http://localhost:8080/WS/Greeting?wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial shows how to host service without server. It's wrong to publish web application on server this way. Server applications doesn't need main method.
In order to run EE application, you need web.xml file.

Follow this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/ to deploy jax-ws application on Tomcat. Hoever, Tomcat is only Servlet container, so you must provide jax-ws implementation by yourself.

JEE applications should be hosted on EE Servers - like Glassfish, Tomcat EE or Jboss, for name a few. They have EE libraries built in.

Take a look:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html

Comment: I understand im a noob at this. I have deployed the server on Tomcat and it says its active etc, but don't i have to build a client to receive the output? That is what i am having an issue with. Thanks.

Comment: No, you should be able to view wsdl just using browser. Did you added jax-ws libraries to tomcat lib?

Comment: I have added it to the Tomcat as a war file. Running the Tomcat and booting to the Web Services page. I click on the WSDL link and it brings me to an XML Tree. Is there any further tutorial out there that could give me steps at this point? (My main goal is to get a shell started to send a xml and recieve it back if its approved to be written into a dirrectory) I understand java language but im clueless to the soap/jax idea. Overall i guess im just asking what do i do from this point, how can i edit things from this page. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, it's great that web service is running. Now you have to implement client from WSDL - it's pretty easy from now. Just follow this tutorial: http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.ws.cxf.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcreate_client.html

WSDL just desribes your service: it shows what messages and operations can be invoked on your service. It's generated from `@WebService` and `@WebMethod` annotations. You can edit wsdl file and create service from it, or write java code and then wsdl file will be automatically generated (it's top down or bottom up)...